# How to send text and file from html to Node JS?

Tags: html, node.js

I want to send text data as well as image file from HTML to Node JS.
Please help me.

Comment: Please post your code here

Comment: You might wanna google this term AJAX

Answer (score 1):

Just send [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) to server. And in node use [multipart-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) middleware to get form parameters. ( included in body-parser )

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) for that. It will parse the files and form data for you.